# python dataframe group by column unique values and count group size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` where the 'categories' column contains a variable length  of  string  labels   to that row. Each label represents a sub-category:

```
id         categories               number

1         'food','toy','science'    1
2         'animal'                  2
3         'plant','food','science'  5
....
```

Added code  here to generate such dataframe:

```
d = {'id': [1, 2,3], 'categories': [["food","toy","science"],["animal"], ["plant","food","science"]],\
     'number':[1,2,5]}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dd['categories'] = dd['categories'].astype('str')
dd['categories'] = dd['categories'].str.replace('[','')
dd['categories'] = dd['categories'].str.replace(']','')
```

How could I do a group-by and count by each sub-category size in the column 'categories'?

```
df.groupby('categories').size()
```

if calculated this way, id1 and id3 will be grouped differently but id1 and id3 both belong to 'food' sub-category.

I could split 'categories' column into different columns and then do the groupby  column by  column. Since I have 200 strings in that `categories` column, this sounds cumbersome.
Any  elegant solution?

if I use `df.to_dict` it will be like:

```
{'id': {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3},
 'categories': {0: 'food','toy','science', 
                1: 'animal', 
                2: 'plant','food','science'}}
```

If I only use top 3 rows as example, expected output will be:

```
categories      size
food            2
toy             1
animal          1
plant           1
science         2
```

Comment: Does number represent the count for the categories?  For the sub-categories would the count for food for instance be 6 (1 from id 1 plus 5 from id 3)?

Comment: The df constructor you've provided is not a valid python dictionary. The values should probably be either lists or strings. Please edit to fix the ambiguity.

Comment: Does 'categories' column contains a **list** of string labels , or one big string of comma-separated quoted labels? This determines whether you'll use `explode` or `str.extractall`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to create a row for each sub-category for category column.

Starting with df DataFrame:

```
    id  categories  number
0   1   'food','toy'    1
1   2   'animal'    2
2   3   'plant','food','science'    5
```

**Code**

```
# Following steps
df['categories'] = df['categories'].str.split(',')    # convert categories from string to list
df2 = df.explode('categories')                        # explode categories
                                                      # category column now only has one sub-category per row
result = df2.groupby('categories').size()             # group sub-categories and 
                                                      # count number of items in each group
```

result

```
categories
'animal'     1
'food'       2
'plant'      1
'science'    1
'toy'        1
Name: number, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This works and also elegant.  pyspark has explode function. it's good to know pandas also has one.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `str.extractall` then `value_counts`

```
out = df.categories.str.extractall("'([^']*)'")[0].value_counts()
Out[947]: 
science    2
food       2
plant      1
toy        1
animal     1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```